# How can I sum specific property from same object that are in different lists using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using java 8 Streams API, how can I sum all values of specific propertie of equal items in different lists ?

For the example, I have the following code:

```
public class Streams {

    static class PurchaseItemCancellation {
        private Integer id;
        private BigDecimal quantity;

        // constructor
        // getters and setters
    }

    static class PurchaseCancellation {
        private Integer id;
        private List<PurchaseItemCancellation> purchaseItemsCancellations;

        // constructor
        // getters and setters    
    }

    public static void main (String ... args) {

    PurchaseItemCancellation item1 = new PurchaseItemCancellation(1, new BigDecimal("10.00"));
    PurchaseItemCancellation item2 = new PurchaseItemCancellation(2, new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    PurchaseItemCancellation item3 = new PurchaseItemCancellation(3, new BigDecimal("30.00"));
    PurchaseItemCancellation item4 = new PurchaseItemCancellation(4, new BigDecimal("40.00"));

    PurchaseCancellation purchaseCancellation1 = new PurchaseCancellation(1, Arrays.asList(item1, item2));
    PurchaseCancellation purchaseCancellation2 = new PurchaseCancellation(2, Arrays.asList(item3, item4));
    PurchaseCancellation purchaseCancellation3 = new PurchaseCancellation(3, Arrays.asList(item4, item1));

    List<PurchaseCancellation> cancellations = Arrays.asList(purchaseCancellation1, purchaseCancellation2, purchaseCancellation3);

    final Comparator<PurchaseItemCancellation> byID = (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getId(), p2.getId());

    // List<PurchaseItemCancellation> itemsCancellations = cancellations.stream() ....

    }
}
```

The `List<PurchaseCancellation> cancellations` has lists of cancellations on which each cancellation has a list of `PurchaseItemCancellation`;

So I need is sum all value from properties "quantity" of same item for each list of `PurchaseItemCancellation` contained on each cancellation.

The result must be a `List<PurchaseItemCancellation>`:

item1: id: 1, quantity: 20.00

item2: id: 2, quantity: 20.00

item3: id: 3, quantity: 30.00

item4: id: 4, quantity: 80.00

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process outlined in the following code is this: take the stream of `cancellations` and convert it to a stream of `PurchaseItemCancellation`. Then we just perform a basic summation of that. (**Edit** I just noticed that for reasons that completely escape me, you are using `BigDecimal` values. That requires a slightly different approach.)

```
List<PurchaseItemCancellation> = cancellations.stream()
    .filter(c -> c != null)
    .map(PurchaseCancellation::getPurchaseItemCancellations)
    .filter(l -> l != null)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PurchaseItemCancellation::getId,
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, PurchaseItemCancellation::getQuantity, BigDecimal::add)))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new PurchaseItemCancellation(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is one line of code, but broken into the seven above lines it may be clearer what's going on.

1. Convert to a `Stream<PurchaseCancellation>`
2. Filter out the odd `null` cancellation - I don't know if this is a concern.
3. Convert to a `Stream<List<PurchaseItemCancellation>>`
4. Filter out any cancellations which had a null list - again, don't know if you have to worry about this.
5. Convert to a `Stream<PurchaseItemCancellation>` - no longer grouped by which cancellation they came from
6. Use a fancy converter which groups by `id` and within each group sums up the quantities. Now you have a `Map<Integer, BigDecimal>` from id to quantity
7. Convert this map into another stream of the entries
8. Convert it into another `Stream<PurchaseItemCancellation>`
9. Get a list of this final result.

Sometimes it's easier not to use streams, y'know?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The result must to be a unique list of PurchaseItemCancellation with no repeated items. But with each value for item.quantity summed. So there will be a unique item1 with your quantity added from others occurences in other lists.

Comment: With your answer I get close to the solution. I accumulated all  PurchaseItemCancellation in a single list, but I have repeated itens. How can I merge the same items (grouped by your ID) adding the item.quantity ?

Comment: The above may not be the most efficient way of doing it. In particular, I think it ought to be possible without going through an intermediate `Map` but I'm not sure how. Also, the dangers of rounding with `double` values is very slim, if you plan on engaging in non-microscopic quantities. Your examples are all effectively integers despite the additional decimal points. If they truly are integers, use `int`/`long`; otherwise `double` should be fine.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!
I agree with you. Sometimes streams becomes very complicated.

Comment: In these example I have used simple numbers to facilitate the calculations. But in real problem, I work with 4 decimal numbers of precision.